# MEAN.JS Contact Form

Tags: angularjs, forms, contacts, meanjs

Trying to create a contact form and feedback form for my website. Here is my route and controller I'm using however I need to understand what's going on with my routes and how to capture the input fields from the form implement this inside MEAN.JS:

`route.js`:

```
app.route('/mail').get(mail.createmail);
```

`app/controller.js`:

```
    exports.createmail = function(req, res) {

    var mailOpts, smtpTrans;
    // create reusable transporter object using SMTP transport
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'administrator@radleaf.com',
            pass: '34Girls34*goo'
        }
    });

    // NB! No need to recreate the transporter object. You can use
    // the same transporter object for all e-mails

    // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'Fred Foo ✔ <foo@blurdybloop.com>', // sender address
        to: 'ty@radleaf.com', // list of receivers
        subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world ✔', // plaintext body
        html: '<b>Hello world ✔</b>' // html body
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });

 };
```

Not sure how this work with the HTML with the view:

```
<form action="mail">...</form>
```

Comment: @joker I'm not understanding why I got a negative mark with zero solution on this. Please advice Joker...

Comment: Joker your being super mean to me now help me out :-( My code is re-edited and I need a better insight on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're asking how you can gather data which is input into a form, send that data to expressJS, and then use that data to send an outbound email.

If so, then here is your flow:

Step 1: Create a form in a view and map it to an **AngularJS controller**

```
<form name="contactForm" data-ng-submit="sendMail()">
Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="contact_name">
Message: <input type="text" data-ng-model="contact_msg">
<button type="submit">
</form>
```

Step 2: In your AngularJS controller, use a $http request to send your data to your Express Route

```
$scope.sendMail = function() {
// Simple POST request example (passing data) :
$http.post('/mail', {name: contact_name, msg: contact_msg}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
}
```

Step 3: Use your ExpressJS Route as an API to call your ExpressJS Controller.
(It looks like you've got this bit covered)

```
app.route('/mail').get(mail.createmail);
```

Step 4: Receive and do something with the data passed through the $http POST

```
exports.createmail = function(req, res) {
var data = req.body;
```

Now you can use the data, like this

```
   var mailOptions = {
        from: data.name, // sender name
        text: data.msg, // plaintext body
    };
```

MeanJS 0.4.0 also has a working example of NodeMailer which might help: https://github.com/meanjs/mean/tree/0.4.0

Comment: I needed a better insight on 'Step 4' once again you are super awesome Shrizzy. Please email or call me when you have the time. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

With angularJS, you can remove the action attribute, and just use angularJS ngSubmit directive, and call a function in your controller which would now visit the endpoint with $http.get.